# Initial run through of a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, dom-events, callstack, event-loop

In Javascript, whenever an asynchronous operation/event is called, a message is created along with the operation/event's callback function (a function which only runs after the operation/event has finished).

When the operation/event is complete (or triggered) the message moves onto a message queue. This message queue is polled constantly (this polling is known as "the event loop") and, when a message is found in the queue, the message's callback is placed on the callstack and run. We then return to the event loop and either wait for a new message or grab the next message in the queue and run its callback.

My question is: before all of this, when a JavaScript file is first run, is everything run on that same callstack before the event loop starts up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty interesting question. Someone will no doubt provide a better explanation as I don't fully understand what is going on, but from my testing I have determined that the answer to your question is no.

Take the following code example:

```
alert( 'start' );

var cats = document.getElementById( 'cats' );

cats.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert( 'cats' );
});

cats.click();

alert( 'finish' );
```

The alerts fire as follows: `start`, `cats`, `finish`. The fact that `cats` appears before `finish` proves that message are being added to the event loop as the code is being executed, not after.

http://jsfiddle.net/3bm2pz86/

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up Christian. It's now got me wondering if the event loop must do a tick after each line is executed in the stack.

Comment: @Nathan Perhaps, but unfortunately this is beyond my knowledge. If you happen to do some research and figure it out, please come back and post your findings!